# Android NDK Standalone Toolchain with C++11 support

Tags: android, c++, c++11, android-ndk

I have to write a Wifi Sniffer for Android for my bachelor thesis. The sniffer itself is written in C++ using [libtins](http://libtins.github.io), "a high-level, multiplatform C++ network packet sniffing and crafting library." It works fine and without problems. Now I need to use that code in my Android app. Therefore I'm trying to cross compile libtins in order to use my code on Android.

In order to compile it I set up a standalone toolchain from the Android NDK with the following command:

```
make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-19 --install-dir=/home/henrik/Bachelorarbeit/Sources/lib/Android-19_Toolchain --toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-4.8 --stl=libc++
```

libtins uses cmake in it's build system. I followed the cross compile tutorial on the libtins homepage. As I also compile it with the -std=c++11 flag on my host system (debian 7 btw) I try to use C++11 with the NDK as well. **But** running the following command

```
cmake ../ -DLIBTINS_ENABLE_WPA2=0 
-DLIBTINS_ENABLE_CXX11=1 
-DLIBTINS_BUILD_SHARED=0 
-DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=/home/henrik/Bachelorarbeit/Sources/lib/Android-19_Toolchain/
-DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY=ONLY 
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/home/henrik/Bachelorarbeit/Sources/lib/Android-19_Toolchain/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-4.8
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/home/henrik/Bachelorarbeit/Sources/lib/Android-19_Toolchain/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-4.8
```

gives me this error:

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/henrik/Bachelorarbeit/Sources/lib/Android-19_Toolchain/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-4.8
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/henrik/Bachelorarbeit/Sources/lib/Android-19_Toolchain/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-4.8 -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /home/henrik/Bachelorarbeit/Sources/lib/Android-19_Toolchain/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-4.8
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /home/henrik/Bachelorarbeit/Sources/lib/Android-19_Toolchain/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-4.8 -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Setting build type to 'RelWithDebInfo' as none was specified.
-- Build will generate a static library.
-- Found PCAP: /home/henrik/Bachelorarbeit/Sources/lib/Android-19_Toolchain/lib/libpcap.a 
[shortened]
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:60 (MESSAGE):
 C++11 features requested but the compiler does not support them.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

which confuses me since according to the NDK documentation C++11 is supported. Turning off C++11 support for libtins makes cmake run through.
However, compiling gives an error since ifaddrs.h is not found. I found [this](https://github.com/kmackay/android-ifaddrs) git repository which offers a ifaddrs.h file that I could cross compile with the same standalone toolchain creating a static lib. Adding this lib and its header file to the libtins directory solves the *ifaddrs.h: no such file or directoy* issue but causes a another one:

```
...libtins-master/src/network_interface.cpp: In member function 'bool InterfaceInfoCollector::operator()(const ifaddrs*)':
.../libtins-master/src/network_interface.cpp:96:85: error: 'const struct ifaddrs' has no member named 'ifa_ifu'
info->bcast_addr=IPv4Address(((struct sockaddr_in*)addr->ifa_ifu.ifu_broadaddr)->sin_addr.s_addr);
```

Seems like the ifaddrs.h I used does not work as the normal one provided by linux.

Does anyone know how to solve this? I'm afraid the C++ code I wrote contains some C++11 specific methods (not sure here, it just works on my host system) thus I don't want to miss that feature (apart from that, libtins runs faster with C++11).
Is there any way to get this working or do I have to rewrite that sniffer in C using libpcap which would take a lot of time since it, at least for me, seems more complicated than what I've got so far with libtins.

Thanks in advance =)

**EDIT**

After trying to run cmake with C++11 support enabled the cmakeerror.log contains the following line: `CheckFunctionExists.c:function main: error: undefined reference to pcap_get_pfring_id` 
the libpcap I compiled for android doesn't contain it. 
I compared my host system's libpcap with the one for android and found following differences:

**libpcap.a CC for Android 19 in total**

```
pcap-linux.o
pcap-usb-linux.o
fad-gifc.o
```

**libpcap.a from my host system 21 in total**

```
pcap-linux.o
pcap-usb-linux.o
pcap-can-linux.o
pcap-netfilter-linux.o
fad-getad.o
```

The ones coming after fad*.o are the same (at least their names are). I don't know if that is due to the different architecture or if something went wrong...

Comment: The second error is pretty straight forward: Looking at the ifaddrs.h you included, that member is not present. What does the config.log or similar say about the C++11 feature failure?

Comment: AFAIK, the config.log is created when compiling, right? As I'm not even getting to the compile step. Calling make after the failed cmake command ends up with a _no targets selected_ error.

Comment: No, config.log should be generated when configure / similar are running -- e.g., where the tests are failing in our output above.

Comment: You do realize that this is probably only going to work on root-hacked devices?  And that unless you substantially alter the device configuration, only from a helper executable, and not from a JNI library linked into an app process which will lack sufficient permission?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes I'm aware of that. I have a rooted device so that's not the problem. I can require root access in the manifest and thus the app has root access which would make the code work. Correct me if I'm misssing something x)

Comment: You are indeed missing a lot: even on hacked devices, **root does not apply to an application process itself** but only (at most) to a helper executable.